# Add to cart button, Not working on 2.4.2

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.4, addtocart, mini-cart

After update magento (from 2.3.4 > 2.4.2) and migrated on a new hosting, Add to cart button stop working.

After i select a product and then "Add to cart" button, website is reloading on same page, but no product added on mini cart. Even if i navigated on /checkout/cart, cart is empty.

The problem appear on category view, product details even in homepage.

- I have allready clear cache (from magento and CLI).
- Change template to default, with no results
- Reindexing, many times (from magento and CLI)
- checked on var/log/*.log files, with no errors
- checked console log for errors, nothing

Any idea?

Comment: i dont know if its important, magento 2.4.2 is on subdomain until works fine (newversion.glowfashion.gr). In main domain there is a magento 2.3.4, which works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me: [was here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Upgrade-from-2-3-5-to-2-4-0-Issue-with-cart/m-p/456245#M3759)

Some modules was disable from **app/etc/config.php**
*I ran the following commands:*

```
php bin/magento module:enable --all
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer Below Url and check

- https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-magento-2-add-to-cart-button-not-working/

  OR 
  please run  below command
  **rm -rf var/cache/***

Comment: thnx for your reply, in my core_config_data table i have 2 rows: with path design/head/includes. The values are:"<base href="https://newversion.glowfashion.gr/">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/pub/media/porto/web/css/mycss.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pub/media/porto/web/js/my.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pub/media/porto/web/js/jquery.remove-upcase-accents.js"></script>" Any way i have allready try this, change all value with https://newversion.glowfashion.gr, with no results.

Comment: please run all magento command and check in private browser